# Crystal Reports - Prints on 5 end user's machines but doesnt print on the newest member's pc

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

We have an Internal system that uses crystal reports to print a checksheet.
When I deployed this project, I had to do the following:

1. install Crystal Reports SP30 32bit runtime
2. install ODBC for MySQL 32/64bit

Once this was done on the other 5 user's the system printed as intended.
However with the newest member of the team, i have setup the system  like all the others but it comes up with the error

> File temp error: database connecter error

When I test the connection, it comes back as successful and so I'm just looking for advice on anything else to try within crystal reports / runtime's / Visual studio to try fix this issue

The user is on the same network, on the same OS.

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to crystal reports unable to find database.
Open crystal report file in that system and give database connection to .rpt files once database server established error will be solved. Also open database in that system.
If you establish the connection in that system still you get error than check database profiler for checking query error.
If possible give port number or ip address to database and change connection string accordingly in applications.